# Plotting two datasets in same ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, scatter-plot, errorbar

I am trying to plot together in the same plot the following information:

1. Scatterplot of two variables (`jobcontrol` and `jobdemands`), coloured differently for five groups (`class` variable).
2. for each of the five groups, I would like to show the mean value for the two variables (`jobcontrol` and `jobdemands`), surrounded by a double error bar in horizontal for X-ax variable and vertical for the Y-ax variable. This would should the central tendency and dispersion of each of the groups.

Snippet of the data:

```
> head(karasek1)
   jobcontrol jobdemands    class
          9         37          1
         26         37          1
          9         30          5
         NA         NA          4
         11         42          2
         29         42          1
```

And the data for plotting means and error bars:

```
desc2 <- data.frame(class=c(1:5),
                       jcmean = c(23.23, 24.79, 28.31, 23.26, 23.84 ),
                       jcse = c(5.95, 5.23, 6.05, 6.33, 5.91),
                       jdmean = c(36.40, 37.71, 38.16, 35.04, 36.48),
                       jdse = c(5.86, 5.23, 5.39, 6.60, 5.90))
```

This is my temptative solution:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data=karasek1,aes(x=jobdemands,y=jobcontrol,color=class,shape=class))+
  geom_point(size=1) +
  geom_errorbar(data=desc2,aes(ymin=jcmean-jcse,ymax=jcmean+jcse),width=.1,position =position_dodge(0.1)) + 
  geom_errorbarh(data=desc2,aes(xmin=jdmean-jdse,xmax=jdmean+jdse),width=.1,position =position_dodge(0.1))
```

It does not work, it has to do with combining two data together as the error message is:

```
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'jobdemands' not found
```

An additional issue is that I do not know how to get these error bars coloured according to the different values of `class`, so that there is five "crosses" and they can be recognized.

Thanks very much in advance!

Comment: Your first errorbar has a ymin and a ymax, but no x position. You need to tell ggplot *where* to put the errorbar. The error is because you previously mapped `x = jobdemands` so it's looking for a `jobdemands` column in `desc2` to know where to plot the errorbar. Similarly your horizontal error bar will need a `y` position.

Comment: As long as your `class` is a factor in both data frames (can't tell from your example about your data, it's definitely not in `desc2` so use `as.factor()`), then the `color = class` you have in your initial `aes()` will work for coloring the points and errorbars.

Comment: Thanks @Gregor! can you be more specific about the position to be provided to the error bars in your first comment? I've tried several forms of´xmax´ and ´xmim´  but still the very same error message.

Comment: It need an `x`, not an `xmax` or `xmin`. Presumably, the error bars correspond eo the `jobdemands` that you already have mapped to your `x` axis, so all you need is a column called `jobdemands` in your `desc2` data, and the `x = jobdemands` will be inherited by default from your initial plot.